# What are the benefits of Poker graduating from beta to full SE site and the requirements for doing so?

Tags: support, specific-question

I see that this site has been in beta for quite some time now - mostly due to low question frequency it seems.

I was wondering what benefits (if any) come with the site making it out of beta and graduating to a full Stack Exchange site?

Also, what are the exact requirements for the site to graduate out of beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posts you want to read are [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614) and [Feedback Requested: Design-Independent Graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260754).

The main criterion is the number of questions per day reaching 10. When this happens, the Community Team reviews the state of the site, trying to determine whether there are enough active and reputation-empowered users for the site to hold a moderator election. If they approve graduation, then (from a post linked above):

> - the beta label is removed
> - elections are held
> - migration paths are set up
> - community ads are run
> - a link to the site is added to the footer
>
> ...Then, as it becomes available

- the site gets their custom design.
- privilege thresholds are increased to graduated site levels

"beta" label is removed, and election is held. The site does not get its custom design at the same time; that takes several additional months (sometimes over a year).

Poker is nearing its 5th birthday, and is [averaging 0.9 questions per day](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday). I would not expect graduation within the next couple of years (or ever), unless something changes in the online habits of many poker players. But, as the post I linked affirms, the lack of graduated status is not a "black spot" -- the site still has a home on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that post - it has certainly clarified things for me around the criteria for graduation. Are the only benefits of graduation removal of the "beta" label, moderator elections and (at some point) a custom design?

Comment: Also, your [questions per day](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) link does not work for me, just redirects me to [this page](https://stackexchange.com/sites#).

Comment: I added the list of graduation perks, and linked to the source. Don't know what's up with the link, but you can probably see Poker's stats on that site anyway.